# Swift 3 Popover Dim Background

Tags: swift, uiview

I have read multiple places with suggestions on how to accomplish this. I went with adding a UI view in the background and setting it to disable and then after showing the popover, setting the view to enable.

As you can see it looks to work nicely:

[image]

But I do have two problems. The first one is once the popover is presented, you can tap anywhere on the background to dismiss the popover. Is there anywhere to block this from happening? I assumed my background UIView would block any inputs.

Also, after the popover is dismissed, the screen is still dim. I tried the following but neither of them load after dismissing the popover so the View never gets set back to disable:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
         dimView.isHidden = true
    }

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
         dimView.isHidden = true
    }
```

**EDIT:**

This is the code that I use to present the popover:

```
  let popover = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PopoverVC")

        popover?.modalPresentationStyle = .popover
        popover?.popoverPresentationController?.delegate = self as? UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate


        popover?.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.view
        popover?.popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect = CGRect(x: self.view.bounds.midX, y: self.view.bounds.midY, width: 0, height: 0)

        popover?.popoverPresentationController?.permittedArrowDirections = UIPopoverArrowDirection(rawValue: 0)

        dimView.isHidden = false

        self.present(popover!, animated: false)
```

Comment: used dimView.isHidden = true in dissmiss view controller view did appear not called

Comment: How do I add it to the popoverVC? Currently its an outlet in the main view controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realize that, dimView is not in PopoverVC, add it into PopoverVC and handle dismiss when tap on it.After the popover is dismissed viewDidAppear and viewWillAppear will not be called. So your screen is still blurry.If you add dimView into Popover, hope you can solve these issuses

Comment: How do I add it to the popoverVC? Currently its an outlet in the main view controller.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could solve your two problems with the UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate and a protocol/ delegate to tell the presenting viewcontroller when your are dismissing and hide your dimView.

The first issue can be implemented like this:

```
extension YourViewController: UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate {

    func popoverPresentationControllerShouldDismissPopover(_ popoverPresentationController: UIPopoverPresentationController) -> Bool {
        return false
}
```

For the second issue you can pass a function through delegation. Hopefully this link will help with that.

https://matteomanferdini.com/how-ios-view-controllers-communicate-with-each-other/

Cheers